# Camera won't open in Moto X

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I am trying to open camera in Moto X device using MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE.Following is the code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, cameraUri);
if (intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            TelloApplication.getInstance().setInBackgroundWithSafeMode(true);
            if (chooser) {
                context.startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, context.getString(R.string.perform_action_with)),
                        attachmentChoice);
            } else {
                context.startActivityForResult(intent, attachmentChoice);
            }
        }
```

The issue is intent.ResolveActivity is null. Is there a way to ressolve this issue or this is bug in the device?

Comment: Apparently, that device does not ship with a camera app that supports `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. There is very little that you can do about this directly.

Comment: Just found out that there is no camera app in the phone.

Comment: That is even more surprising. You could suggest a camera app to the user, that they could install from the Play Store (or F-Droid or wherever). Or, you could integrate camera features directly in your app, such as by using the Fotoapparat or CameraKit-Android libraries.

Comment: Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818679/image-not-loading-when-capturing-from-the-camera-in-nougat/49818830#49818830), might solve your problem.

Comment: @AmitJangid My issue is different. In my case camera intent dont open on specific phone... else it is working fine

Comment: Is there any errors in your log cat?

Comment: Nope. It was just that there was no camera app to support intent in the device.